# Number of elements of the group $SL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $p$ a prime, what is the number of elements of the group $SL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$, $k \ge 1$?

I can answer the $k=1$ case. For each element of $SL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, there are $p-1$ scalar multiples in $GL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Picking an element of $GL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is equivalent to choosing 6 linearly independent vectors in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^6$. So$$|SL_6(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})| = {1\over{p-1}} \prod_{k = 0}^5 (p^6 - p^k).$$But for $k > 1$, I do not know.

Comment: You can look at the modulo homomorphism $SL_6(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)\to SL_6(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$. What is its kernel?

Comment: Just checking that you mean to refer to the ring of integers modulo $p^{k}$, and not the finite field of order $p^{k}$?